# TYPO3 Flexform reset after change

Tags: typo3, flexform

A question of understanding: I use flexform in combination with container and TYPO3 12. It works as expected.
But now I have noticed that when changes are made to a flexform, a kind of reset occurs (sometimes). This means that the default values are selected again for elements that have already been created.

Is this also the case for you? And if so, when exactly does this happen and how can it be prevented?

Thank you!

Comment: I remarked this bug once in one form of the install tools, so it's not completely unknown for me. Just for the case that there is some javascript working, you can't do much against it, but usually that shouldn't be the case. Update TYPO3 to the latest version, clear the browser cache and cookies, and try again. If you still have the error after that consider filing a bug on https://forge.typo3.org.